# wpf how to save and load image from database - what approach?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a desktop application using wpf.I will need to store some pictures and show them after.I need a textbox with the link to the database,and that will be saved in a database.They told me that the best approach is to save a image path to the database,not the image itself.
Is that better then blob?I can't find any example with the path on the new,only with blob...

Comment: "I can't find any example with the path". That's just storing a string. However, if the images are only a few, and they are small, storing them as blob might be preferrable.

Comment: and when I wanna load the picture do I just read the path from the database field,and then set the picture with that url?that's it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save image to the database as a link, but beforehand rename it to GUID to ensure uniqueness of reference you will be storing

Comment: why a normal id wouldn't do the job?

Comment: This is to avoid two trips to database, where first would be to check what was the last id used. Also, you avoid issues as synchronization and potential giving same id to two images. I would imagine that you rename the image to GUID and then insert the link to the database.

Answer (score 0):

/*this is my code , and you can save an image into datebase*/
namespace WpfApp1
{

```
public partial class saveImage : Window
{
    public saveImage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    OpenFileDialog Op = new OpenFileDialog();
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Op.Title = "image selection";
        Op.Filter = "JPG(.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG(.png)|*.png|JPEG(.jpeg)|*.jpeg";

        if (Op.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            img1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Op.FileName));
        }


    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PersonAccountingdbEntities db = new PersonAccountingdbEntities();
        tbl_Setting set = new tbl_Setting();
        set.Image1 = File.ReadAllBytes(Op.FileName);
        db.tbl_Setting.Add(set);
        db.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("image has been saved");


    }


}
```

}